# Struts 2 Validation Adding Field Error to List

Tags: java, validation, struts2, ognl

My form has a parameter consisting of a grid/table (presented via s:iterator) of data together with other fields represented in my action class as:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
  private MyParameter param;

  public String execute() { ..... }
  // getter and setters 
}
```

Here is MyParameter class:

```
public class MyParameter {
  private List<GridData> gridDataList;
  private String subParam1;
  private String subParam2;
  // getters and setters here
}
```

Here is GridData:

```
public class GridData {
  private String title;
  private String arg1;
  // etc... getters and setters...
}
```

I am able to successfully submit the values of grid data to perform some validation. I am able to add field errors to other parameters by this:

```
super.addFieldError("param.subParam1", "subParam1 error message");
super.addFieldError("param.subParam2", "subParam2 error message");
```

What I would like to do is to iterate through my list, and add error messages to each of the elements in the list. I tried doing the following but it does not seem to work:

```
for(int intRow=0; intRow < param.griDataList.size(); intRow++) {
  super.addFieldError("param.gridDataList[" + intRow + "].arg1", "error message");
}
```

I then rendered the field errors in JSP using iterator. I know that the above is possible because when I check the generated HTML after processing, the field show the 'cssErrorClass' that I have set in JSP. That is:

```
<s:textfield
name="param.gridDataList[%{#outerStat}].data"
cssClass="grid_text_field"
cssErrorClass="error_field" maxlength="7"/>
```

Where outerStat is the status (counter) set in the iterator.
This generates:

```
<input
type="text"
name="param.gridDataList[0].data"
class="grid_text_field error_field"
maxlength="7"/>
```

But no field error message is generated in the tag:

```
<s:fielderror fieldName="param.gridDataList[%{#outerStat}].data"/>
```

Can anyone kindly point out what I have done wrong here?

Comment: what is `intRow`? are you iterating the collection?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, I have updated question to clarify the usage of intRow. Yes, I am iterating through the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct usage of fielderror tag is `<s:fielderror fieldName="some_field_name"/>`.
And some_field_name must be String not expression http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/fielderror.html.

One of the way to do this is to access fieldError map in property tag 
`<s:property value="fieldErrors.param[%{index}].arg"/>`

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. I corrected the sample code. In my actual code, I used `fieldName` instead of `name`. I mistakenly wrote it that way. The error is successfully registered but is not printed out. Is `s:property` tag the only way?

Comment: Why don't you like `s:property` tag? If you want to style field error then you can write table cells and css class yourself.